# How to resolve the circular dependency problem between freetype and harfbuzz libraries?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, cross-compiling, sdl-2

I am currently trying to compile a static C++ application on Linux for Windows. I am using the `x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-g++` compiler and used `mxe` to install the static 64bit versions of the libraries `sdl2`, `sdl2_image`, `sdl2_ttf` and `boost`. I keep running into these errors, and I think it has something to do with the circular dependency between `freetype` and `harfbuzz`:

```
/home/user/.mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-ld: /home/user/.mxe/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libharfbuzz.a(libharfbuzz_la-hb-ft.o):hb-ft.cc:(.text+0x11fd): undefined reference to `FT_Get_MM_Var'
/home/user/.mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-ld: /home/user/.mxe/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libharfbuzz.a(libharfbuzz_la-hb-ft.o):hb-ft.cc:(.text+0x126b): undefined reference to `FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates'
/home/user/.mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-ld: /home/user/.mxe/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libharfbuzz.a(libharfbuzz_la-hb-ft.o):hb-ft.cc:(.text+0x1366): undefined reference to `FT_Done_MM_Var'
/home/user/.mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-ld: /home/user/.mxe/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libharfbuzz.a(libharfbuzz_la-hb-ft.o):hb-ft.cc:(.text+0x1676): undefined reference to `FT_Set_Var_Blend_Coordinates'
```

This is the part of my Makefile in which I add the libraries:

```
WIN_STATIC_LIB = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lcairo -lharfbuzz -lbz2 -lstdc++ -lm -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -lsetupapi -lwebp -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lSDL2_test -lsamplerate
```

Comment: `-lfreetype` after `-lharfbuzz` or potentially in both positions (before and after) if there is circular dependence. Or wrap the two libraries in `--start-group` and `--end-group` to have the linker repeatedly do this until everything is resolved automatically.

Comment: I wonder what pkg-config would output.

Comment: SDL_ttf has [submodule-vendored](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/tree/main/external) copies of FreeType and Harfbuzz, why not use those?  See their `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`, `SDL2TTF_VENDORED`, and `SDL2TTF_HARFBUZZ` CMake options.

Comment: @user17732522 I tried adding `-lfreetype` in both positions and it now compiles without errors, but the application still does not open correctly on a windows device. It takes a while and then Windows tells me that the program is not responding. Any ideas?

Comment: @TomGebel That seems unrelated to this question. Also probably impossible to answer without seeing a [mre].